# freebsd 9.1 apache-mpm php5 child segmentation fault

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault, pthreads, freebsd

I've got such problem:
When I run script which uses pthreads extension, PHP crushes with this errors:

```
[notice] child pid 44688 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[notice] child pid 44689 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I have installed apache22-worker-mpm port, php5.4.16 with pthreads 0.44

Also command

```
ps -U www
```

provides such result:

```
PID   TT  STAT     TIME  COMMAND
44687 ??  TX    0:00:00  /usr/local/sbin/httpd -k restart
44688 ??  S     0:00:00  /usr/local/sbin/httpd -k restart
44689 ??  Z     0:00:00  <defunct>
44690 ??  S     0:00:00  /usr/local/sbin/httpd -k restart
```

Restarting apache - does nothing.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

PS: on my Windows machine - all works fine, so problem isn't in php code.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in investigating crashes is to obtain the stack from the core-dump.

Obtaining core-dump of Apache may be tricky -- because they are often disabled by default. But [it can be done](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CoreDump).

Now, the fact that it works on Windows is not, actually, proof, that it is not the php-code -- whatever the problem is, it may be triggered by the "just right" sort of racing between threads. The OS, the number of CPUs, and other factors all affect the results of a race...

And finally, are you sure, you are using thread-safe (zts) version of PHP itself?